# jquery .css() not applying -webkit-transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot see what is wrong with this code. Calculate center position of window then transform-translate div there (have to use translate for what i am doing).

Just getting this working for Chrome for a start, hence the -webkit- prefix).

Very confused as to why jQuery does not apply the inline style to the .logo div. Have included my other trouble-shooting experiments, commented out.

A syntax problem? jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spacewindow/7f7rt/3/).

```
var centerPosition = '';

function centerLogo(){
  var w_width = $(window).width();
  var w_height = $(window).height();
  var hCenter = (w_width / 2) - 150;
  var vCenter = (w_height / 2) - 150;
    console.log(hCenter);
    console.log(vCenter);
  var centerPosition = 'translate(' + hCenter + 'px, ' + vCenter + 'px);';
    console.log(centerPosition);
  $('.logo').css('-webkit-transform', centerPosition);

  // Try uncommenting the three examples below - they all work ...

  // $('.logo').css('background', 'blue');

  // centerPosition = 'blue';
  // $('.logo').css('background', centerPosition);

  // $('.logo').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(10.85px, 45.56px)');

}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  centerLogo();
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `css` method, on versions >= 1.8.0, will add vendor prefixes as necessary; no need for you to manually specify.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon in your declaration of `centerPosition`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/7f7rt/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correcy syntax of `$('.logo').css('-webkit-transform', centerPosition);` does not have semi colons inside the Strings. Try changing this:

```
var centerPosition = 'translate(' + hCenter + 'px, ' + vCenter + 'px);';
```

to this:

```
var centerPosition = 'translate(' + hCenter + 'px, ' + vCenter + 'px)';
```

Should work: http://jsfiddle.net/7f7rt/6/

Comment: and how does this help?

Comment: The correcy syntax of `$('.logo').css('-webkit-transform', centerPosition);` does not have semi colons inside the Strings.

Comment: are you sure, coz' its not working in the jsfiddle... please check it again.

Comment: rather the answer given below by Alpesh is working. There is no issues with the semi colons.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks for your help everyone. Good to know about the jQuery prefixing too.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Sure Work.

```
    var posElem = document.getElementById('logo'); // set id to div 

    var newStyle = '-webkit-transform: translate(' + hCenter + 'px, ' + vCenter + 'px);' +
   'transform: translate(' + hCenter + 'px, ' + vCenter + 'px);';
   posElem.setAttribute('style',newStyle);
```

Comment: Comment this line. $('.logo').css('-webkit-transform', centerPosition); and don't forget to change the id logo of your div.